# Send Exception and Json with spring MVC

Tags: json, spring-mvc, exception, http-status-codes

I'm trying to manage exceptions in a Spring MVC context and send different http statuses in response.

I tried this :

`@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE)
    public class UnavailableServiceException extends RuntimeException {
}`

When I send this exception in my controller, it works fine : response http status is 503.
But I want my controller to send json, and with this configuration, when 503 is send, response is html :-/

So I tried this :

Removing @ResponseStatus on my exception class and defining an Exception handler.

`@ExceptionHandler(UnavailableServiceException.class)
public ResponseEntity<ExceptionJSONInfo> handleUnavailableService(UnavailableServiceException exception) {
    return new ResponseEntity<ExceptionJSONInfo>(new ExceptionJSONInfo("Error xxx", exception.getMessage()), HttpStatus.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE);
}`

It's ok : 503 and json.
But I want to manage 5 or 6 different exceptions : how can I do this without duplicating handlers ?
Is it possible to retrieve @ResponseStatus defined on an exception ?

If not, my next idea will be to define an httpStatus attribute in a super class, mother of all my exceptions. And then :

`public class UnavailableServiceException extends MySuperException {
  super(HttpStatus.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE);
}`

`@ExceptionHandler(MySuperException.class)
public ResponseEntity<ExceptionJSONInfo> handleUnavailableService(MySuperException exception) { 
    return new ResponseEntity<ExceptionJSONInfo>(new ExceptionJSONInfo("Error xxx", exception.getMessage()), exception.getHttpStatus());
}`

Any better idea ?

Thanks

Manu

Comment: Are you throwing exceptions by yourself or you're also handling the run-time exceptions?

Comment: I didn't ask myself the question ... but handling both will be better.

Comment: then you can use Exception.getMessage() method for exceptions thrown by you, considering, you are passing the message in constructor while throwing exceptions.